# Apply a fade effect on deferred images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, deferred

I implemented a blur effect, using a very tiny and light image that's loaded first, since it is very light, and once the background image is loaded, the deferring process will replace the `data-src` with the actual image.

My problem with it is the sudden change, making the background image blink. I want to find a way to gracefully "load", with a fade effect mainly.

Below's the code:

```
function init() {
    let imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]');
    for (let i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
            if (imgDefer[i].tagName === 'IMG') {
                imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
            } else {
                let style = "background-image:url({url})";
                imgDefer[i].setAttribute('style', style.replace("{url}", imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the element:

```
<header class="header header-inverse h-fullscreen p-0 overflow-hidden" data-src="assets/img/headerbg.jpg" style="background-image: url('assets/img/headerbgprev.jpg');"> ... </header>
```

Comment: You can't transition one image into another when you're changing the image source.  I'd suggest having 2 images - the real one and the lighter one, but have the lighter one placed directly in front of the real image.  Once the real image has loaded then you can use whatever your preferred method (please say css) to make the front image fade out and then remove it (if required).

Comment: Actually I've done exactly that before.  Use the selector you have to identify the images you want to preload, and then wrap them with a container div (position:relative) and insert an image into it that's the same width and height as the original image. Position that absolute (left:0, top:0) and then you have all the pieces to do what you need :)

Comment: The image is a `background-image` rule, I guess I forgot to specify it. The question is updated with the piece of code.

Comment: In that case, just use a css transition to fade the foreground image opacity to 0, and then remove it (if needed).

Comment: Your suggestion gave me an idea. Sorry if it is what you suggested me. I will show what I did here.

Comment: That's pretty much what I meant, but I can give you a more generic solution.    I'm just putting something together for you.  I hope you like cats :)

Comment: Ah sorry then, hehe.

Comment: No that's okay - It's good that you try different things.  My solution is just a suggestion - take what you need from wherever to get the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, for this problem, I created an empty `div` with the following rules:

```
header .preview-bg {
    background-image: url(assets/img/headerbgprev.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

And I added this to the deferring script:

```
$(imgDefer[i]).find('.preview-bg').fadeOut(500);
```

If someone has a better alternative to prevent specific selection like this, something that would work for many background images at once, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.  It identifies elements with a `data-src` attribute (as you already had) and then adds a cover element (in this case an image, so you can use an image url if you want to, but it could be anything).  It then does a background load of the image at the url in `data-src` and, once it's loaded, it sets the background image and fades out the cover.

This is obviously a quite generic solution, but it should be more than enough to do what you need and be able to modify to make it sing and dance as much or as little as you like :)

```js
function init() {
    let imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll('[data-src]');
    for (let i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        (function(deferred) {
          if (deferred.getAttribute('data-src')) {

              var cover = new Image();
              cover.className = "fading-cover";
              deferred.appendChild(cover);

              var preloader = new Image();
              
              // I've added this setTimeout so you can see the effect
              // as if the images are loading for the first time.
              // Remove the setTimeout and leave the preloader.src line
              // in the finished version
              setTimeout(function() {
                  preloader.src = deferred.getAttribute('data-src');
              }, Math.random() * 3000);
              
              preloader.addEventListener("load", function() {
                deferred.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + deferred.getAttribute('data-src') + ")";
                cover.style.opacity = 0;
              });
          }
        })(imgDefer[i]);
    }
}

init();
```

```css
div.image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
div.image .fading-cover {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" data-src="https://cmeimg-a.akamaihd.net/cute-article-rcp/cme/cuteness_data/s3fs-public/diy_blog/Why-Are-Some-Cats-More-Vocal-Than-Others.jpg"></div>
<div class="image" data-src="https://cmeimg-a.akamaihd.net/cute-article-rcp/clsd/getty/f32e47a02653426f8f9dbb1553892225"></div>
<div class="image" data-src="https://cmeimg-a.akamaihd.net/cute-article-rcp/cme/cuteness_data/s3fs-public/diy_blog/14-tips-that-Could-Extend-Your-Cats-Life.jpg"></div>
```